# How install B2B Suite in Shopware 6?

Tags: php, composer-php, shopware, b2b

Is it possible to install B2B Suite in Shopware 6 with Composer?

My approach so far has been

```
composer require shopware/b2b

php bin/console plugin:install SwagB2bPlatform
```

But this leads to an error when I try to install the plugin

> The class "SwagB2bPlatform\SwagB2bPlatform" is not found. Probably an class loader error. Check your plugin composer.json

Does anyone have any experience with this? Do I have to run any scripts to make sure the plugin has all the necessary resources?

Comment: Did you add a custom registry for `shopware/b2b` and is there a folder below `custom/plugins` name `SwagB2bPlatform`?

Comment: No, after composer installation the folder SwagB2bPlatform is located in `vendor/shopware/b2b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shopware has no way to simple way to require proprietary plugins. You should not use SwagB2bPlatform as composer repository via vcs as all needed assets get packed before the release.

You can setup [packages.friendsofshopware.com](https://packages.friendsofshopware.com/) for your projects. This is a community driven project which provides a repository of all plugins in the community story. You are limited to plugins that you bought in the community store. Using this repository needs an extra entry in the repositories in your composer.json. After that you can just require any plugin that is assigned to your project. In the search you can find the plugin you look out for: https://packages.friendsofshopware.com/?producers=shopware%20AG&term=b2b